# Why do they use a spray gun to apply stain to decks but not to hardwood floors?

Tags: flooring

I am seeing that a spray gun+ air compressor can be used to spray stain on decks.

Why can't this be done the same way on hardwood floors?

Comment: Overspray and all the aerosolized stain floating as a mist in the room - covering everything ...

Comment: Nothing is stopping you, but 99.9% of people are not happy with the mess or the time it takes to cover everything including the walls.

Comment: You can, if you'd prefer, use a roller & brushes on the deck. It's just quicker to spray and the over spray isn't a big issue on the lawn. @brhans - write that up as an answer. I'll give it a vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a sprayer *always* results in some overspray, and the product being sprayed will always be "aerosolized" to some degree, resulting in it floating in the air.
When this is done outdoors on a deck or similar area, the overspray rarely matters, and the aerosolized product just gets blown away.
However, when spraying indoors you'd have to mask off absolutely every surface in the room (walls, doors, windows, even the ceiling) to prevent the aerosolized product from covering the entire room.
The degree to which the product gets aerosolized and floats about depends on its volatility and how "thick" it is.
You'll find that something relatively 'light and thin' like a wood stain will aerosolize much more readily and hang about longer than a heavy water-based latex paint (but even latex paints can get very messy of you're heavy-handed with the sprayer).

Comment: very true. I did spray my deck and I should have remembered those vapors :-))